# Changing the case of a single character in the middle of a string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm cleaning up a data set. One of the difficulties is that some of the rows have wrestler names merged with wrestling company names without spaces.

```
Date        Match
2001-06-16  American Dragon Defeats Jerry LynnMCW
1943-10-07  Lou Thesz Defeats Jack McDonaldGAC 
1955-03-25  Buddy Rogers Defeats Danny McShain
```

To fix this, I use the following line to remove the company name by getting rid of a capitalized letter and everything that comes after if that capital follows a lower case letter:

```
data_set_2 <- data_set %>%
mutate(match = str_remove(match, "(?<=[:lower:])[:upper:].*"))
```

However, in the case of names with multiple capitalizations, like McDonald,  the result looks like this:

```
date        match
2001-06-16  American Dragon Defeats Jerry Lynn
1943-10-07  Lou Thesz Defeats Jack Mc
1955-03-25  Buddy Rogers Defeats Danny Mc
```

To fix this, I've tried to make it so that names only have one capitalization, by trying to lower a capital that comes after `Mc`:

```
data_set_2 <- data_set %>%
mutate(match = str_to_title(match, "(?<=Mc)[:upper:]"))
```

However, the below is the result:

```
Date        Match
2001-06-16  American Dragon Defeats Jerry Lynnmcw
1943-10-07  Lou Thesz Defeats Jack Mcdonaldgac 
1955-03-25  Buddy Rogers Defeats Danny Mcshain
```

As you can see, it is lowering everything, and not isolating the lower to just the one letter. I'm trying to think of a way to isolate the one character, but nothing I've tried has worked. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just a space between the person's name and the company name? Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Hey jsb, I would like to separate the space between the person's name and the company name. However, I'm trying to solve for the unintended consequence of names with multiple capitalizations getting swept up as well, due to how I'm removing the company names.

Comment: Are the company names always three capital letters, e.g. MCW?

Comment: Many are, but not exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

If the company names are all-caps, as in your first two examples, you could replace the empty string matched by the following regular expression with a space: `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z]{2})`. `(?<=[a-z])` is a positive lookbehind, requiring the match to be preceded by a lowercase letter. `(?=[A-Z]{2})` is a positive lookahead, requiring the match to be followed by two uppercase letters. If the second character of the company name can be lowercase there is no logical way to determine if the substring is just a name or a name followed by a company name (e.g. `MacDonald`).

Comment: Hey Cary, Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I've tried the below, but its not seeming to change anything. Any thoughts? Thanks!


```data_set_2 <- data_set %>%
mutate(match = str_replace(match, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z]{2})", "(?<=[a-z])\" \"(?=[A-Z]{2})"))
```

Comment: I tried the below, and its not exactly what I was going for, as some of the run-ons are not acronyms, but most are, so this is getting me some of the way there.

```mutate(match = str_remove(match, "(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]{2,}.*"))```